# sending mails with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i have a form where the users will be able to send their messages to different mail ids. The form has fields like from, to, subject etc. the users will give their mail id in the 'from' filed and the receiver's mail id in the 'to' fields. the problem is i'm not being able to send mail though i think my code is ok. Does CodeIgniter allow to send emails in this way??

**Controller**

```
class Email_send extends CI_Controller {   

    function Email_send()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
    }

    function index()
    { 
        $config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'subject'  => $this->input->post('subject'),
            'message'  => $this->input->post('message'),
            'from'    => $this->input->post('from'),
            'to'  => $this->input->post('to'),
        );

        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

        $this->email->initialize($config);

        $this->email->from($config['subject']);
        $this->email->to($config['to']); 

        $this->email->subject($config['from']);
        $this->email->message($config['message']);  

        if($this->email->send())
        {
            $this->load->view('success_em');
        }

        else
        {
            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
        echo form_open('Email_send', $attributes); ?>

<p>
        <label for="from">Your mail ID <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <?php echo form_error('from'); ?>
        <br /><input id="name" type="text" name="from"value="<?php echo set_value('from'); ?>"  />
</p>

<p>
        <label for="to">To <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <?php echo form_error('to'); ?>
        <br /><input id="to" type="text" name="to" value="<?php echo set_value('to'); ?>"  />
</p>

<p>
        <label for="subject">Subject of the mail<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <?php echo form_error('subject'); ?>
        <br /><input id="subject" type="text" name="subject"  value="<?php echo set_value('subject'); ?>"  />
</p>


<p>
        <label for="message">Your Message<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <?php echo form_error('message'); ?>
        <br /><textarea id="message" style="width:300px; height:80px" type="text" name="message"  value="<?php echo set_value('message'); ?>"  /></textarea>
```

**Error**

```
The following SMTP error was encountered: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 ko8sm6157345pbc.40
502 5.5.1 Unrecognized command. ko8sm6157345pbc.40
The following SMTP error was encountered: 502 5.5.1 Unrecognized command. ko8sm6157345pbc.40
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Thu, 23 Aug 2012 14:54:54 +0000
From: 
Return-Path: 
To: xxxxx@gmail.com
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?xxxxx@hotmail.com?=
Reply-To: "hello" 
X-Sender: hello
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <5036443e415e4>
Mime-Version: 1.0


Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

hello
```

Comment: Have you checked your logs? What error are you getting?

Comment: I take it you're seeing the "success" message from your code, otherwise you would have posted the message it prints from $this->email->print_debugger()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to authenticate first. You miss these two parameters:

```
$config['smtp_user'] = "user@gmail.com";
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'yourpassword';
```

Comment: yes i'm trying to send from local server to hotmail or gmail. the response is added plz check. thanks.

Comment: do u know is it possible to send mail to yahoo or hotmail in this way? thanks

Comment: You can send to any email either it is Yahoo or Hotmail. Just Authenticate to your Gmail as explained. Just set the destination email to $this->email->to("email@domain.com");

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to add `subject`, `message`, `from`, `to` in the `config` object your passing to init the email class.

Try removing these and include the SMTP authentication keys as Hatem suggested.

**E.g.**

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'user@gmail.com';
    'smtp_pass' => 'yourpassword';  
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate first. You miss these two parameters:

```
$config['smtp_user'] = "user@gmail.com";
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'yourpassword';
```

Add them beside other configurations.